# How do I fix 403 forbidden error for IPNs?

Tags: apache, server, http-status-code-403

Several days ago my Apache server started denying access to PayPal IPNs (payment notifications). On the IPN detail pages it says: HTTP response code 403. I am at a loss, because prior to that everything worked just fine. I didn't change any settings. What could be causing this and how do I fix it? I have access to WHM (WebHost Manager).